# I cannot find where these errors occur nor what they even mean to fix them

Tags: lua

> [ERROR] bin.tonumber takes exactly 2 arguments
> [FATAL] Error while calling Lua implementation of 'virtual bool GameState::build()'

> [ERROR] [string "GameState.lua"]:5850: attempt to index field '_data' (a nil value)
> [FATAL] Error while calling Lua implementation of 'virtual bool EBDS::build()

CONTEXT:
I have a prebuilt game that runs on its own, but when I try to switch to that game from a lobby, it crashes during initialization. I can only assume that the first error causes the others because I've traced back all through GameState.lua and cannot find any difference between this and the two working games.
Putting my own traces in the code, I know this error occurs before the initialization is even began.

I just got a job at this company with no experienced programmers to ask and those that I have asked have no idea.
If I need to update with snippets of code please tell me, because I don't have the foggiest where to begin looking beyond what I've already dug through.

Note: if relevant, I'm using a program called Slot Constructor IDE and coding in Lua

Comment: Start with looking at line #5850 and understand why `_data` field is absent in the table.  You probably have something like `t._data[idx]` in your code, and `t._data` is nil.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly my first thought. I dove down through that and all the code is exactly duplicate to the working projects. So my only subsequent thought was the bin.tonumber error was causing the compiler to not finish doing some process required of it. But doing a "Find in Files" through notepad++ shows that EVERY single call of bin.tonumber has exactly two arguments.

Comment: Since it doesn't tell me a line I have absolutely no idea what could be causing that error aside from some additional compilation thing that doesn't trigger an error. I have now placed a print line at the start and end of every file and have thus discovered the error occurs between the loading of two files, but I have no idea what process could be occurring at that time. If I come up with more information I will edit this question from there.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is, these errors don't seem to be caused by lua itself, more like the compiler (or game engine) has some requirements your script doesn't meet. Another guess is that someone messed with the lua source... (I would comment this because this isn't an actual answer but my reputation is to low)